# Search for more elegant way to handle many nested try with resources

Tags: java, try-catch

I am searching for more elegant way to handle problems where we need to have many nested try with resources ,which are dependednt from one another. Example of such case:

```
        try (MDC.MDCCloseable test= MDC.putCloseable("test", test)) {
        try (MDC.MDCCloseable paw= MDC.putCloseable("paw", test.getPaw().toString())) {
           try (MDC.MDCCloseable tru = MDC.putCloseable("tru", paw.getTRU().toString())) {
              try (MDC.MDCCloseable mdcKey = MDC.putCloseable("rtu", paw.getKey())) {
                 try (MDC.MDCCloseable rtu= MDC.putCloseable("rtu", "test")) {
                    try (MDC.MDCCloseable ito= MDC.putCloseable("ito", rtu.getIto())) {
                        ...
                    }
                 }
                 try (MDC.MDCCloseable eht = MDC.putCloseable("eht", "eht")) {
                       try (MDC.MDCCloseable epr= MDC.putCloseable("epr", eht.getEPR())) {
                       }
                 }
                 try (MDC.MDCCloseable lkt = MDC.putCloseable("lkt", "lkt")) {
                    try (MDC.MDCCloseable plo= MDC.putCloseable("plo", lkt.getPlo())) {
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason those have to be **nested**? Because you can define more than one resource in a single try and the code above doesn't really make it clear why you don't just do that.

Comment: Yes they have dependencies between them. Like to depends of rtu ,per from eht and plo from lkt.I can make them a little bit less nested ,but still they are multiple tries and looks ugly for me

Comment: That still doesn't automatically mean you can't put more than one in a single try. eG `try (ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bao.toByteArray())) { ... }` is perfectly valid java. Using a Resource that you declared in a try in the same try later on is perfectly possible.

Comment: As noted, you can put all of this in a single `try (...; ...; ...;) { }`. You could also refactor some of this into method calls (where each method opens its own try-with-resources).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to put all resources to the same `try`?

Here is simplified example:

```
try (MDC.MDCCloseable test= MDC.putCloseable("test", test);
     MDC.MDCCloseable paw= MDC.putCloseable("paw", test.getPaw().toString()) {
    /// etc, etc.
}
```

Comment: and what about this which depend of the previous ones.

Comment: try (MDC.MDCCloseable rtu= MDC.putCloseable("rtu", "test"); try (MDC.MDCCloseable ito= MDC.putCloseable("ito", test.getIto())) {
                     
                    } Is it ok if ito depends of rtu?

Comment: It is not a problem. Even my small example contains such case. `test` is created first, `paw` uses it. Both will be closed when the job is done.